# Replace string to <img> tag JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I've a string like this : `var a="hello :D".`
So, I want to replace the `:` char  to `<img>` using jQuery.

I did it like this:
  `var message = a.replace(':', '<img src=\'emoticon/01.gif\' />');`

But when in run my application it's not working!
Please help me,thanks so much!

Comment: Could you clarify "not working"? What happens when you run the code, and how does it differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message, and if so, which? The `replace` method only replaces the first occurance when you use a string as the first parameter, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use back slash to escape `:`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TgWzs/1/)**

```
var result = a.replace(':', '<img src=\'emoticon/01.gif\' />');
```